# By what principle is a message sent to Socket.io

Tags: node.js, dom

I have the given code

```
socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log("check");
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = msg;
    messages.append(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

Why does it only send a message if there is a variable "messages", it is not announced anywhere, meets for the first time, does not send with other names, how so?

Comment: This code does not send messages, it "listens" and receives messages. From your description it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not nodejs code, it's browser Javascript.

Somewhere in the environment in which your code appears, somebody has done something like this:

```js
const messages = document.querySelector('ul#messages')
```

to retrieve the DOM Element for an unordered list `<ul id='messages'>...</ul>` containing incoming messages.  Then, your code appends the newly received message as a list item `<li>` to the end of that unordered list.

If the `messages` item isn't available your `socket.on` event handler gets an error on calling `.append()` and returns immediately. Check your browser devtools for error messages.